# Fatou's Lemma without MCT

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(\mathbb{R^d},\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space, $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure, and $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of non-negative measurable functions. Then

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R^d}} \liminf_{n\to\infty}f_n~d\mu \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R^d}} f_n~d\mu.$$ This can be easily proved using MCT. I am trying to prove it without using MCT. Here is a proof that does not use MCT:
[General Fatou's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126686/general-fatous-lemma). Could you explain why the following equality is true? Is this due to an equivalence of the definition of the integral? Thanks.

$$ \sup_m \int_{X_m}  min( g, m)  = \int_{X} \liminf_n f_n \>
$$
(the last equality from the proof in the above link)